# Class responsibilities OOP design

Tags: c#, object-oriented, classes

I'm having some questions on creating a design for simple approval workflow. Some arbitrary thing (`ItemToApprove`) needs approval process. Approval process begins with creating `ApprovalRoute` which contains several approval steps (`ApprovalStep`). `ItemToApprove` goes sequentially through all steps until gets status `Approved`. On each step there are several `Approvers` with equal priority. If one approver approves item, step becomes `Approved`.

```
public class ApprovalRoute
{
    private LinkedList<ApprovalStep> _approvalSteps;
    private ApprovalStep _currenStep;

    public bool? Approved { get; private set; }

    public void Approve(Approver approver)
    {
        // ... some cheks if already approved etc
        _currentStep.Approve(approver);

        if (_currentStep.Approved == true)
        {
            MoveToNextStep(); // changes _currentStep
        }

        if (AllStepsApproved()) {
           Approved = true;
        }
    }
}

public class ApprovalStep
{
    public bool? Approved { get; private set; }
    private List<Approver> _approvers; 

    public ApprovalStep(List<Approver> approvers)
    {
        _approvers = approvers;
    }

    public void Approve(Approver approver)
    {
        if (_approvers.Contains(approver))
        {
            Approved = true;
        }
    }
}

public class ItemToApprove
{
    public bool? Approved { get; private set; }
    private ApprovalRoute _approvalRoute;

    public void StartApprovalWorkflow(ApprovalRoute route)
    {
        _approvalRoute = route;
    }

    public void Approve(Approver approver)
    {
        _approvalRoute.Approve(approver);
        if (_approvalRoute.Approved == true)
        {
            Approved = true;
        }
    }
}

public class Approver
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Approver(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    // ... ovveriding Equals etc
}
```

So some console client would be like this

```
      var itemToApprove = new ItemToApprove();
      var aprovalRoute = new ApprovalRoute(new ApprovalStep(new List<Approver>
      {
          new Approver("One"),
          new Approver("Neo"),
      });
      itemToApprove.StartApprovalWorkflow(aprovalRoute);

      while (itemToApprove.Approved == null)
      {
          Console.Write("Your name: ");

          string approverName = Console.ReadLine();
          itemToApprove.Approve(new Approver(approverName));

      }
```

I thik this design has some smell because calling `Approve` delegates further down to `ApprovalStep`. The second smell I feel more naturally call `Approve` on `Approver` passing `ItemToApprove`

```
// ....
var approver = new Approver();
approver.Approve(itemToApprove);
```

What do you think?

Comment: Arguably the current step could be exposed as a public property which is calculated each time the property is called, and the `Approve` method removed from `ApprovalRoute`. Technically a Law of Demeter infraction, but feels appropriate in this case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hypothetical code that has not been written fully, and is incomplete. The answer, and the comments on the answer show that the information needed to review the code correctly is not in the code, and is not complete.

Comment: I've made some edits in order to remove `hold because look likes pseudocode`

Comment: I've voted to reopen. It looks much more complete now. And before anyone rolls back the edit because there is already an answer, I say OAP shouldn't have answered an off topic question.

Comment: I have rejected the reopen option for this question because it would invalidate the answer. This question should still remain closed, and with the version of code that was used for the answer. Please put your revised code/question in to a new question, it's the best way to proceed from here. See: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: Well that escalated quickly. This question can be reopened and I revise my answer accordingly. Win-win-win maybe?

Answer (score 3):

**Random thoughts**

In this scenario, there's few implementation details making me ask "why"?

1. In `ApprovalRoute` what benefits `LinkedList<T>` gives over any other `IEnumerable<T>` ?
2. In `ApprovalStep` and `ItemToApprove` classes is it necessary to make `Approved` property    nullable ?
3. Won't it, at least, hurt coder's eyes if `bool` type is compared using equality operator `==` instead of `someBool` or `!someBool` ?

And to anwer myself right-away

1. I think it could be e.g. `Queue<T>` since

> ItemToApprove goes sequentially through all steps until gets status
>   Approved

2. No, because default value will always be `false`, it is never checked if property  `HasValue` and there's no separate logic for `null`s.
3. Yes, it hurts the eyes and makes you say nonconstructive things like "WTF dude". Just don't do it.

On the higher level then

> I think this design has some smell because calling Approve delegates further down to
>   ApprovalStep.
>   `itemToApprove.Approve(new Approver(approverName));`

You are right. Now it feels like the `ItemToApprove` is actually approving something. This method shouldn't exist.

> The second smell I feel more naturally call Approve on Approver passing ItemToApprove 
>   `approver.Approve(itemToApprove);`

Again you are right. But in this case it would seem than approver is approving the item itself, not a step along the route.

---

**Suggestions**

I'd remove the `Approve` method from `ItemToApprove` and `ApproveStep` classes and make it `ApprovalRoute`'s responsibility to dequeue `ApprovalStep`s as they are approved. Dequeued step is the current step and when queue is empty, item is fully approved.

Better yet I'd pass the `ItemToApprove` along the `ApprovalRoute`, not the other way around. You could also have multiple items going down the same route at the same time, all having their own "states".

Something like below.

Related dotnet Fiddle can be found here https://dotnetfiddle.net/6BlA30 (web page "console" seems little buggy though).

---

[image]

```
public class Program
{
    // console app for testing
    public static void Main()
    {
        // some items
        var item1 = new ItemToApprove("item1");
        var item2 = new ItemToApprove("item2");

        // approvers
        var approver1 = new Approver("app1");
        var approver2 = new Approver("app2");

        // steps w/ authorized approvers
        var step1 = new ApprovalStep("step1", approver1);
        var step2 = new ApprovalStep("step2", approver1, approver2);

        // create route
        var route = new ApprovalRoute("route1", new[] { step1, step2 });
        // add items to current route
        route.AddItems(item1, item2);

        // start manual testing
        Console.WriteLine("** {0} has {1} items **", route.Name, route.Items.Count());
        while (route.Items.Any())
        {
            Console.Write("> ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
            var parts = input.Split(' ');

            if (parts.Length == 2)
                route.ApproveStep(new ItemToApprove(parts[0]), new Approver(parts[1]));
            else if (input.Equals("?"))
                route.Status();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("No more items in route");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

**Implementation**

For examples sake all classes are simplistic and inherit abstract `ModelBase`.

```
public abstract class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;

        return (Name == ((ModelBase)obj).Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Actual "business objects" below

```
public class ItemToApprove : ModelBase
{
    private bool _isApproved;

    public ItemToApprove(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public bool IsApproved
    {
        get { return _isApproved; }
        set { _isApproved = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class Approver : ModelBase
{
    public Approver(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class ApprovalStep : ModelBase
{
    public ApprovalStep(string name, params Approver[] approvers)
    {
        Name = name;
        Approvers = approvers;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Approver> Approvers { get; private set; }
}

public class ApprovalRoute : ModelBase
{
    // sequential steps in this route
    private readonly List<ApprovalStep> _steps;
    // items and step indexes
    private readonly Dictionary<ItemToApprove,int> _itemsInRoute = 
        new Dictionary<ItemToApprove,int>();

    public ApprovalRoute(string name, params ApprovalStep[] steps)
    {
        Name = name;
        _steps = new List<ApprovalStep>(steps);
    }

    public void AddItems(params ItemToApprove[] items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (item.IsApproved)
                        Console.WriteLine("Item '{0}' fully approved", item.Name);
                };
            _itemsInRoute.Add(item, 0);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ItemToApprove> Items { get { return _itemsInRoute.Keys; } }

    public void ApproveStep(ItemToApprove item, Approver approver)
    {
        if (!_itemsInRoute.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no '{0}' on '{1}'", item.Name, Name);
            return;
        }

        int index = _itemsInRoute[item];
        var step = _steps[index];

        if (step.Approvers.Contains(approver))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} for {1} approved by {2}", 
                step.Name, item.Name, approver.Name);

            index++;
            if (index > _steps.Count - 1)
            {
                _itemsInRoute.Single(i => i.Key.Equals(item)).Key.IsApproved = true;
                _itemsInRoute.Remove(item);
            }
            else
            {
                _itemsInRoute[item] = index;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} for {1} can only be approved by {2}", 
                step.Name, item.Name, string.Join(",", step.Approvers.Select(a => a.Name)));
        }
    }

    public void Status()
    {
        foreach (var entry in _itemsInRoute)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} at {1}", entry.Key.Name, _steps[entry.Value].Name);
    }
}
```

Hope this made any sense.

Comment: 1.Interesting. I've chosen linked list because of requirement to preserve history of approval process.
2-3 Nullable used because step maybe in 3 states: pending(null), approved(true), rejected(false). For rejection logic is similar to Approve, so I've ommited it

Comment: All the states weren't clear so I made an assumption. Anyway, in example I used List instead of Queue, too. Added fiddle in the answer.